# Data binding check if not null in xml

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I am using data binding to trigger onClick with ImageView.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> listener.zoomImage(view, connectedItem.largeImage)}"
           />
```

The problem is `connectedItem.largeImage` can be sometimes null, and I need that the onClick will no trigger if its null.

I tried:

```
android:onClick="@{(view) -> connectedItem.largeImage?? listener.zoomImage(view, connectedItem.largeImage)}"
```

But the sitax is wrong.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

you can check it inside the zoomImage function, change type of large image to nullable and check it in the function:

if we consider that your function is :

```
fun zoomImage(view:View, largeImage:String){
    //your function logic
}
```

change it to:

```
fun zoomImage(view:View, largeImage:String?){
    if(largeImage != null){
        //your function logic
    }
}
```

Comment: The app crashes before the function in case its null

Comment: please add the crash logs to your post, I will check it